# Multilabel multiclass classifier returns same probabilities for any input

Tags: r, keras, rstudio

I am new to deep learning. I have a collection of website texts and the activity class each company belongs to. A company can list multiple activity classes (NACE-codes)

The goal is to build a recommender that would recommend the five best activity classes based on a website the user provides.

The model is trained on the top 10K most frequent words that occur in the websites. The words are represented as scores ranging from 0 to 1. Each text is a line in the matrix, with 3000 columns (the first 3K words per website are taken into account).

The labels are k-hot encoded (activity class labels are columns and have 1 if the company lists the activity class; otherwise 0)

There is a significant imbalance between the labels, so each label is weighted by dividing the total number of classes by the time each class occurs in the dataset.

When I train the model, the loss goes down and my custom 'precision' score (correct activity class is among the top-5 predictions) goes up somewhat during training. However, when I use the model to predict, it will always return the same scores between 0 and 1 (what you would expect, given the sigmoid layer) for the classes, no matter what the input is. **So, it seems that all the model has learned is that some classes are more likely to occur than others.**

Any suggestions or guidelines would be appreciated. I have read Chollet's "Deep learning with python", but it is not exactly a great source of advice on this particular topic.

My model looks like this:

```
 library(keras)
 metric_precision <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
   metric_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k = 5) 
 }

    model <- keras_model_sequential()
    model %>%
    layer_embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=512, 
     input_length=3000, mask_zero = FALSE, trainable=TRUE ) %>%
    layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
    layer_conv_1d(filters,kernel_size, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_max_pooling_1d(5) %>%
    layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
    layer_conv_1d(filters,kernel_size, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_global_max_pooling_1d() %>%
    layer_dense(ncol(train_y),"sigmoid")

  model %>% compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer = 'rmsprop',
    metrics = c(precision=metric_precision)
  )

  model %>% fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data = list(test_x, test_y),
    class_weight = classweights
  )
```

Comment: When I encode the words as integers and re-train, the model provides different probability estimates based on the input